# Set 2 different text colors in alertdialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, spannablestring, spannable

I am trying to set 2 different colors for the text in a alertdialog, through spannable but unfortunatly all the text stays white.
The String **'message'** **should be green** and the String **'message2' normal white**.

If I **remove** the second String **message2** in below line, everything is as it should be.

```
.setMessage(ssBuilder + message2)
```

Code for the dialog:

```
public static AlertDialog createDarkDialog(Context context, String title, String message, String message2) {
        ContextThemeWrapper ctw = new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.DarkAlert);

        SpannableStringBuilder ssBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(message);
        RelativeSizeSpan largeSizeText = new RelativeSizeSpan(1.0f);
        ForegroundColorSpan foregroundColorSpan = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN);
        ssBuilder.setSpan(largeSizeText, 0, message.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        ssBuilder.setSpan(foregroundColorSpan, 0, message.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctw)
                .setTitle(title)
                .setMessage(ssBuilder + message2)

                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // Do something
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .setCancelable(false)
                .create();
        return ad;
    }
```

How I call the dialog:

```
Utils.createDarkDialog(mContext, "Title:", "This should be green" + "\n\n", "and this should be white.").show();
```

Answer (score 0):

If somebody else encouters such a problem, I solved it by replacing this line:

```
.setMessage(ssBuilder + message2)
```

with this one:

```
.setMessage(ssBuilder.append("\n\n" + message2))
```

Now it works as it should be ;)

Answer (score 0):

My guess, in `setMessage(ssBuilder + message2)` java will coerce the objects to same type (ssBuilder is SpannableStringBuilder and message2 is String) and then concatenate them. During this coerce things are getting messed up.

You can try to create a SpannableStringBuilder for message2 (let's say ssBuilder2) formatted as you want, and then concatenate call `setMessage(ssBuilder + ssBuilder2)`.

Comment: Yes, you ansewred while I was writing :D
I saw just when I reloaded the page

Comment: setMessage (ssBuilder + ssBuilder2)  is wrong you can not apply + operator  on SpannableStringBuilder .